Flutter Cubit not emiting state with null values
I'm using Flutter bloc cubit and equatable to manage a simple form. in the birthday field, i check if it's a valid date and then send it to bloc and works fine. but if user then changes the date i want to make the birthday field null in my bloc, but it just doesn't emit when i send a null value to it.
this is my cubit state
class RegistrationState extends Equatable {

final DateTime? birthday;
final String email;
final String password;

const RegistrationState({
this.birthday,
this.email = '',
this.password = '',
});

RegistrationState copyWith({
DateTime? birthday,
String? email,
String? password,
}) {
return RegistrationState(
  birthday: birthday ?? this.birthday,
  specialty: specialty ?? this.specialty,
  email: email ?? this.email,
);
}

@override
List<Object?> get props => [
    birthday,
    email,
    password,
    ];
   }

and this is my function inside cubit
void updateBirthday(DateTime? birthday) {
  emit(state.copyWith(birthday: birthday));

}

as I said, it works fine when I send DateTime values, but if I send null values it just doesn't emit anything

I often use ValueGetter to overcome this situation

void updateBirthday(DateTime? birthday) {
  emit(state.copyWith(birthday: birthday));

}

Ahh yes, you've discovered the typical problem with copyWith: you cannot "update" a value with a null, because a null value is the same as the parameter not being present (usually). Therefore, copyWith returns a clone of the original object, which will not trigger an event in cubit because two "equal" events are never emitted in a row.

Adding to Randal Schwartz's answer. "you cannot "update" a value with a null" in copyWith. You can update the Registration State with an update birthday method to use everything except the birthday you give it.
class RegistrationState extends Equatable {
    ...

 RegistrationState updateBirthDay({
        DateTime? birthday,
        }) {
        return RegistrationState(
          birthday: birthday,
          specialty: this.specialty,
          email: this.email,
        );
        }
    
    @override
    List<Object?> get props => [
        birthday,
        email,
        password,
        ];
       }

This will always update Birthday to null or anything DateTime of your choice.
Also when the props get evaluated, if the birthday is null, you will have [previousBirthday,email,password] compared to [null,email,password] so your state should change.

This is another great solution.  Yet another is to introduce a "sentinel" that is of the type of the original value but effectively means "not set", and you would look for that instead of null.

Thanks to Md. Yeasin Sheikh, i found a solution using ValueGetter, just updating the value inside copyWith methos like this
RegistrationState copyWith({
//change this
ValueGetter<DateTime?>? birthday, 
String? email,
String? password,
}) {  
    return RegistrationState(
        //and this
        birthday: birthday != null ? birthday() : this.birthday
        specialty: specialty ?? this.specialty,
        email: email ?? this.email,
    ); 
}

and then just calling it from cubit function like this
void updateBirthday(DateTime? birthday) {
    emit(state.copyWith(birthday: () => birthday));
}

